# »Er hat ein okayes Wohnzimmer«

Tags: word-usage

Wie verbreitet ist die Verwendung des Wortes *»okay«* (alternative Schreibweise: *»ok«*) als attributives Adjektiv?

Ich habe heute nämlich in den Kulturnachrichten einen Bericht über ein Theaterstück gehört, das in diesen Tagen im Münchner Residenztheater uraufgeführt wird. Als der Regisseur interviewt wurde, sagte er über die Hauptfigur (aus dem Gedächtnis):

> Er hat ein langweiliges aber eigentlich ganz **okayes** Wohnzimmer.

Ist das eine okaye Verwendung des Wortes *okay*?

Comment: Der Kommentarbereich ist nicht für Diskussionsrunden gedacht. Diese wurde [in den Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70458/discussion-on-question-by-hubert-scholnast-er-hat-ein-okayes-wohnzimmer) verschoben. Außerdem nutzt bitte Antworten, um die Frage zu beantworten.

Comment: Wenn es wenigstens ein Forum anstelle dieses unübersichtlichen (und wie ich finde total überflüssigen) Chats gäbe! Wird dieser Chat überhaupt zu etwas anderem benutzt, als dort Kommentare zu deponieren? Wen würde es eigentlich wirklich stören, wenn die Diskussionen genau dort blieben, wo sie geschrieben wurden (und daher meiner Meinung nach auch hingehören)?

Comment: Wir sind 1. kein Diskussionsforum 2. Kommentare dürfen nicht dafür missbraucht werden, dazu gibt es eine [Stackexchange-weite Richtlinie](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Wenn Dir das nicht passt, darfst Du Dich nicht hier beklagen, sondern an der dafür vorgesehenen Stelle: [meta.se]. Unser [Chat] ist aber für solche Diskussionen da. Es liegt leider mindestens auch an Dir, wenn niemand diese Diskussionsplattform  nutzt. Du kannst sogar für jedes eigene spezielle Thema einen eigenen Raum eröffnen, komfortabler geht es kaum noch.

Comment: @Takkat: 1. Ich will gar nicht chaten, daher stört es mich auch nicht, dass niemand diesen Chat benutzt. Ich stelle nicht seine Qualität, sondern seine Existenzberechtigung infrage. Ich will stattdessen an Diskussionen teilnehmen, die auch 5 oder 10 Jahre danach noch genau dort sichtbar sind, wo der Anlass der Diskussion steht. 2. Mir ist diese Richtlinie bekannt, ich halte sie aber für wenig sinnvoll. Ich habe versucht, sie mit meinem Kommentar zu kritisieren. 3. Du hast keine meiner beiden Fragen beantwortet.

Comment: Der Chat wird nie gelöscht, Kommentare häufig. Im Idealfall bleiben keine Kommentare übrig, weil alles wichtige in die Fragen und Antworten eingebaut wurde. Der [Link zur Diskussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70458/discussion-on-question-by-hubert-scholnast-er-hat-ein-okayes-wohnzimmer) bleibt uns hingegen für immer erhalten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Frage ist, in welchem Kontext du es verwendest.

Befindest du dich in einer Standardsprachunterrichtssituation, kannst du es nicht verwenden ohne Gefahr zu laufen, dass der Lehrer den Rotstift in deinem Heft anwendet. ("Gefahr" im Sinne von hundertprozentig.)

In schriftlichen Äußerungen oder in Gesprächen mit Vorgesetzten wirst du es im Normalfall ebenfalls nicht einsetzen, denn du läufst Gefahr, inadäquaten Verhaltens oder mangelnden Sprachvermögens bezichtigt zu werden.

Anders ist es, wenn du genau weißt, was du tust, und wenn du morphologisch problematische Wendungen wie

> die okaye(ne) Zimmereinrichtung

oder

> die zue(ne) Flasche

oder

> die allenen Haferflocken <sup>1)</sup>

einsetzt, um zum Beispiel absichtlich (vielleicht ironisch) besondere Flappsigkeit, Formlosigkeit, Doofheit oder Kindlichkeit auszudrücken, zum Beispiel wenn du - aus welchen Gründen auch immer - den Sprachhabitus eines Achtjährigen imitieren willst.

Der Regisseur vom Residenztheater darf das. Er ist ein Künschtler. Bei ihm gehen wir davon aus, dass er weiß, dass das Wort so nicht standardgemäß eingesetzt ist, und dass wir wiederum wissen, dass er das weiß, und dass er es trotzdem tut, um damit z.B. eben besondere Formlosigkeit oder auch Kreativität auszudrücken oder - sehr wahrscheinlich - den Willen, Grenzräume in gesellschaftlichen Regelsystemen auszuloten.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Die Variante *die allen Haferflocken* erscheint derzeit allerdings auch nichtstandardmorphologisch noch unmöglich; zwingend ist hier die funktionsverdeutlichende Erweiterung um *-en*, die bei den anderen zitierten Formen fakultativ ist. - Der Ausdruck ist übrigens auch übersetzbar mit *die Haferflocken wo alle sind* (jedenfalls in Süddeutschland).

Comment: Du vermeidest, zu begründen, warum ein aus einer Fremdsprache übernommenes Adjektiv nicht nach deutscher Grammatik dekliniert werden sollte (sollte es nicht?). Bei "hip" funktioniert es doch inzwischen auch.

Comment: Ich behaupte ja gar nicht, dass es nicht geht. Allerdings ist die Verwendung bisher auf nicht-standard-sprachliche Kontexte beschränkt. Auch *der hippe Drink* (oder was sonst noch hip sein kann) ist, finde ich, noch leicht jenseits der Grenze des standardssprachlich Akzeptierten. - "Standardsprachlich akzeptiert" würde ich so definieren: in schriftlichen Äußerungen ohne besondere Markiertheit wie Ironie o.ä. einsetzbar. Wobei die Markierung von *der hippe Drink* wohl wäre, dass der Sprecher besonders hip erscheinen möchte.

Comment: Daneben gibt es noch die Babynahrung von Hipp. Ist die auch hip?

Comment: Ich finde ja immer, dass sich Künstler an die gleichen Sprachregeln wir der Rest von uns zu halten haben. Entweder ich darf das auch, wenn ich damit einen komischen Effekt erzielen möchte, oder ich verbiete es dem Künstler.

Comment: Übrigens erscheint mir *alle* kein besonders süddeutsches Wort für *aus* zu sein …

Comment: @Jan. Klar kannst du so sprechen oder schreiben. Das kann dir niemand verbieten. Außer vielleicht Vorgesetzte oder Lehrer oder andere Leute, die Macht über dich haben. Oder du schreitest zur Selbstzensur, weil du vermeiden möchtest, dass andere einen schlechten Eindruck von dir bekommen. Aber natürlich, wenn du ein ganz von allen Zwängen freier Mensch bist: Deine Sprache ist ganz deine!

Comment: @Jan  Das "süddeutsch" bezog sich ausschließlich auf das regionalsprachliche Relativpronomen *wo*.

Comment: Kreativ ist es, etwas neues zu erschaffen. Hier hat der Regisseur sich eines Wortes bedient, das so in der Umgangssprache benutzt wird, er kokettiert also mit der Unterschicht. Kreativ ist daran gar nichts, denn das Wort stammt ja nicht von ihm und der erste, der Umgangssprache in den Kulturbetrieb integriert ist er auch nicht. Zu Kommentar 2: Die Verwendung solcher Phrasen ist selbst das Markieren und bedarf keiner weiteren Markierung.

Answer (score 1):

Das Beispiel zeigt eine okaye Verwendung des Wortes *okay*, aber keine gute im Sinne von standard-, schrift- oder hochsprachlich. Lexikographisch ist *okay* im Deutschen ein per Definition undekliniertes Adverb, aber genauso wie es „substantiviert“ werden kann (etwa in: *jmd. sein Okay geben*), kann es in natürlichen Sprachgebrauch auch „adjektiviert“ oder „verbiert“ (*hat der Chef das schon okayt?*) werden.

Es wirkt aufgrund der aus dem Englischen übernommenen Schreibung etwa seltsam, aber das teilt es gewissermaßen mit heimischen Partikeln, die mitunter dekliniert werden: Es müsste *zuhes Fenster* geschrieben werden, da nur nach einem komplexen vokalischen Kern im Stammmorphem (d.h. nativ *ah, aa, ä/ae, äh, eh, ee, é, ei, ie, ieh, oo, oh, ö/oe, öh, uh, ü/ue, üh*) direkt ein Kern anschließen kann. Hier Bilder aber offensichtlich *ay* den zweistelligen und damit hinreichend komplexen Kern.

Auch die übernommene Lautung ist im Deutschen etwas ungewöhnlich, selbst wenn man es auf /e:/ statt /eɪ/ auslautend ausspricht, denn vor dem Flexionssuffix wäre ein /n/ oder wenigstens ein /h/ statt eines nacktem Glottalstop /ʔ/ zu erwarten. In manchen Dialekten findet sich daher auch das *zune Fenster* und so käme auch ein *okayner Job* linguistisch nicht völlig unerwartet.

Comment: Duden ist nicht einig mit dir - Er behauptet, *okay* sei (zumindestens in der Bedeutung, die hier relevant ist) ein Adjektiv: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/okay_in_Ordnung_bestaetigt , hält sich aber mit Flexionsvorschlägen vornehm zurück. Canoo ebenfalls. http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?input=okay&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de

Comment: Canoo sagt "undekliniert". Damit wäre es *ein okay Wohnzimmer* - Auch nicht viel besser...

Comment: Es gibt verschiedene Ansätze, Adjektive (Nominalattribut), Adverbien (Verbalattribut) und bestimmte Partikeln gegeneinander abzugrenzen.  Dass _okay_ lexikographisch als undekliniert gilt, schreibe ich ja in meiner Antwort, nur würde ich es dann halt als Adverb oder Partikel und nie als Adjektiv (wie traditionell bspw. _lila_ und _rosa_) bezeichnen. Wenn Duden und Canoo das auf Grundlage ihres theoretischen Fundaments doch tun wollen oder müssen, kann ich sie schlecht davon abhalten.

Comment: @IQV seit wann ist *einverstanden* kein Adjektiv?